# R ggplot2 runs in command mode but not in RStudio

Tags: r

I have the problem that a simple script for plotting does run in command but no in RStudio. I even can't figure out where the problem is:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidyquant)
library(ggplot2)

options("getSymbols.warning4.0"=FALSE)
options("getSymbols.yahoo.warning"=FALSE)

AAPL = tq_get(x="AAPL")

AAPL %>%
ggplot( aes(x = date, y = close)) +
  geom_line() +
  labs(title = "Aktienkurs", y = "Schlusskurs", x = "") + 
  theme_tq()
```

In R console mode there is no problem and the Grafik shows up. In RStudio it is not, the error is:

```
Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type function. Defaulting to continuous.
Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type function. Defaulting to continuous.
Fehler: Aesthetics must be valid data columns. Problematic aesthetic(s): x = date, y = close. 
Did you mistype the name of a data column or forget to add after_stat()?
```

And if I change the command to:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidyquant)
library(ggplot2)

options("getSymbols.warning4.0"=FALSE)
options("getSymbols.yahoo.warning"=FALSE)

AAPL = tq_get(x="AAPL")


  ggplot(data=AAPL, aes(x = date, y = close)) +
  geom_line() +
  labs(title = "Aktienkurs", y = "Schlusskurs", x = "") + 
  theme_tq()
```

The same error.
If I fetch the error with:

> rlang::last_error()

```
<error/rlang_error>
Aesthetics must be valid data columns. Problematic aesthetic(s): x = date, y = close. 
Did you mistype the name of a data column or forget to add after_stat()?
Backtrace:
 1. (function (x, ...) ...
 2. ggplot2:::print.ggplot(x)
 4. ggplot2:::ggplot_build.ggplot(x)
 5. ggplot2:::by_layer(function(l, d) l$compute_aesthetics(d, plot))
 6. ggplot2:::f(l = layers[[i]], d = data[[i]])
 7. l$compute_aesthetics(d, plot)
 8. ggplot2:::f(..., self = self)
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see the full context.
```

And if I run

> rlang::last_trace()

```
<error/rlang_error>
Aesthetics must be valid data columns. Problematic aesthetic(s): x = date, y = close. 
Did you mistype the name of a data column or forget to add after_stat()?
Backtrace:
    █
 1. ├─(function (x, ...) ...
 2. └─ggplot2:::print.ggplot(x)
 3.   ├─ggplot2::ggplot_build(x)
 4.   └─ggplot2:::ggplot_build.ggplot(x)
 5.     └─ggplot2:::by_layer(function(l, d) l$compute_aesthetics(d, plot))
 6.       └─ggplot2:::f(l = layers[[i]], d = data[[i]])
 7.         └─l$compute_aesthetics(d, plot)
 8.           └─ggplot2:::f(..., self = self)
```

I know that I am missing something but I just can't figure it out...

Comment: Are you using the latest version of Rstudio?

Comment: What does `names(AAPL)` return?  It looks like it's treating `date` or `close` as a function, not a column name.  You'll get a warning, but does `ggplot(AAPL, aes(x = AAPL$date, y = AAPL$close))....` work?  Just to try narrowing down the problem

Comment: And since it's only an RStudio, maybe restart your session with reloading any state from previous sessions (see https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-to-clear-the-r-environment/14303/7)

Comment: @CodingBiology, simple as that. Now it is running...

Comment: @Coliban glad it helped. I also ran into some troubles that were solved by just updating Rstudio.